# Why passive voice is not used here?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

> Basketball has not only become a popular sport to play , but it has also become a popular sport to watch.

I found the sentence above in a textbook. I'm wondering why passive voice is not used here? Is it acceptable if I say:

> Basketball has not only become a popular sport to be played , but it has also become a popular sport to be watched.

Comment: Writer’s choice.

Comment: The thing ***to be done*** is ask yourself why you wouldn't just refer to the thing ***to do***.

Answer (score 2):

Because in your example you can convey the same meaning more succinctly with active voice. Normally, passive voice is used when there's a contextual reason for preferring it over its active counterpart. That means that unless you have such a contextual reason, active voice is the default, if you will.